# Disk I/O & size performance

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have a process that needs to do a lot of disk writes but no read. I can either write a lot of small files (~1,000,000,000 files, what I'm currently doing) or write a few big files.

Small files are ~2Kb on average but as I have a 4096b block size, I'm loosing about one half on my disk capacity.

However, as a lot of threads needs to write in the as the same time, wouldn't big files be a bottleneck since each thread will need to open the file, write, then close it?

To summarize, what is the best for I/O and space optimization between:

- A lot of small files
- A few big files

Comment: Why not use a database instead - this will abstract your problem to a system designed to handle writes,caching etc.

Comment: All threads in a process use the same file descriptor (which belongs to the process, not to individual threads).

Comment: @davidgo Which databases are suitable for that?

Comment: That really depends on your data - especially how data is going to be retrieved and worked with. For a standard sql type database look into mysql or postgres, but depending on the nature of your data, risks related to lost data etc a nosql database (which Im not that familiar with but come in lots of flavours) may be better - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Comment: Databases do not use file descriptors (in the interface with programs) - typical sql databases treay each row seperately unless you add locks or constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest might be to let [*write-caching*](https://linuxconfig.org/improve-hard-drive-write-speed-with-write-back-caching) determine how frequently *actual* HDD (or SSD) writes are made. You can turn write-caching on or off at the OS level, or experiment with various [*hdparam* settings](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Tune-Your-Hard-Disk-with-hdparm). This enables tuning without altering your application. See [Unix StackExchange on tuning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/can-i-configure-my-linux-system-for-more-aggressive-file-system-caching).

Another possibility is to write to a RAM-disk, and periodically move data to the HDD.

**Caveat:** Increasing write latency increases the possibility of data loss, though if you're using a laptop or PC with UPS, that might not be an issue.

Comment: I didn't know about write caching, quite interesting